# Where to get historical Finland railways map for 1939 year?

Tags: transportation, maps, railroads, finland

Where to get Finland railways map for 1939 year ?

Just want to compare logistics possibilities during Winter War.

It is map of USSR: 
http://soldat.ru/files/f/00000583.jpg

Answer (score 9):

The [National Land Survey of Finland](https://www.maanmittauslaitos.fi/en/e-services/karelian-maps) site has [digital maps from before 1939](https://www.maanmittauslaitos.fi/en/e-services/geodata-portal-paikkatietoikkuna) available for viewing, [including Karelia](https://www.maanmittauslaitos.fi/en/e-services/karelian-maps) [(below)](http://www.karjalankartat.fi/).

[image]